# adapter.noitfyDataSetChanged() does not work with AutoCompleteTextView when used before/after textView.setText

Tags: java, android, material-design

I am developing an android app and using Material Design for UI. As mentioned [here](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Menu.md#exposed-dropdown-menus), I'm using `AutoCompleteTextView` inside a `TextInputLayout`.

Consider an example of a school app. There are two drop-downs. First one to select a class and second one to select a student of that class. When user selects a class (let's say std. 5), we at runtime load names of all the students studying in class 5. Then user can select any student using the second drop-down.

I want, when a user (a teacher) select a class from first drop-down, the second one should automatically be reset and when user clicks on the second drop-down, it should show all the students' names.

My approach is:

```
class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    List<String> classNames, studentNames;
    ArrayAdapter<String> classAdapter, studentAdapter;
    AutoCompleteTextView classDropDown, studentDropDown;

    private void updateStudents(String selectedClass) {
        studentNames.clear();
        studentNames.addAll(getStudentNamesFromDB(selectedClass));
        studentNames.notifyDataSetChanged();
        // studentDropDown.setText(null); if I un-comment this line, then the above line "notifyDataSetChanged" doesn't work. It will show previous options only
    }

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        classDropDown = findViewById(R.id.class_actv);
        studentDropDown = findViewById(R.id.student_actv);

        classNames = getClassNamesFromDatabase();
        classAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.dropdown_ui, R.id.tv, classNames);

        studentNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        studentAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.dropdown_ui, R.id.tv, studentNames);

        classDropDown.setAdapter(classAdapter);
        studentDropDown.setAdapter(studentAdapter);

        classDropDown.setOnItemClickListener(
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Selected class: " + classNames.get(position));
                String selectedClass = classNames.get(position);
                updateStudents(selectedClass);
            }
        );
    }
}
```

The problem here is:
Suppose someone first selected class 5, and selected a student from class 5. Now user realises his mistake and wants to select a student from another class (let's say class 6), when he selects class 6 from 1st drop-down, the value shown on the second view should be cleared automatically.

With design, when I select class 6th, the previously selected name (student from class 5) still appears on the textView. I need that to be reset.